# How to make tab focus buttons available in VoiceOver (Accessibility) mode only

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, wordle-game

I'm using ReactJS and I have a lot of `<button>` in my code. I notice that I can use the **Tab** key to move over the button and there will be an outline on focused button like this:
[image]

But on [this website](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html) which I'm trying to replicate, the buttons they use do not get Tab-focused on normal but just when we turn on the VoiceOver accessibility mode.
And the border of the Tab focus is also different.

[image]

I wonder how can we implement this in React?

Changing `tabIndex` to `0` or `-1` doesn't work.

Thanks everyone!

---

### Update

I ask because this leads to a problem:

- If I use the UI Keyboard (UIKB) first and then try to type with the real keyboard keydown event. The tab focus would just stuck on the UIKB letter and return it twice.
- This doesn't happen on the Wordle game because they just allow using tab focus when in accessibility mode.
- `tabIndex = -1` doesn't work because I want to allow the user use the tab focus just in a11y mode like Wordle, I don't want to totally disable it.

[image]

Comment: You _could_ set `outline: 0`, but note that [hiding accessibility outline is generally considered an accessibility antipattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline#accessibility_concerns).  I imagine that you could make an argument in the case of Wordle that the dev allows direct physical keyboard input from the user for the letters, so this is less critical.  FWIW, they aren't simply preventing the focus indicator on the buttons on the Wordle site-- they prevent tab from focusing them entirely.

Comment: `Changing tabIndex to 0 or -1 doesn't work.` Really?  Can you share a [mcve]?  Setting to `0` wouldn't do anything, but `-1` I would have guessed would prevent focus...

Comment: Why would you want to only make your buttons accessible to one type of screen reader, i.e., VoiceOver? There are many different types of screen reader (JAWS, NVDA, Narrator, TalkBack) and in any case some users don't use screen readers at all, and rely exclusively on the keyboard to manipulate the webpage controls (such as users with mobility impairments). The visible focus rectangle that appears by default when you tab across `<button>` elements is also very helpful for users with visual impairments, so I'd strongly recommend you don't implement a design that removes it.

Comment: @George Because users can use both real keyboard input and the UI keyboard to type. This leads to a problem that if I click the UI Keyboard (UIKB) and then try to type with KB input, the tab focus would stuck on the UIKB. That's why I want to ask why in the real Wordle game, they only allow tab focus when in a11y mode (maybe not only VoiceOver but many more). 

Please check out my update above for the screenshot. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderNied Hi, I have updated my question why it doesn't work in my case. I want to disable the tab index and display it in a11y mode only, I don't want to completely disable it with `tabIndex= -1`. Just like you said above with Wordle case - If they prevent it entirely, how can we able to put it back just in a11y mode?